# How to force pasting from a certain type of clipboard in windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, clipboard

Certain Programs, e.g. Microsoft OneNote, copy selected text both as an image and as plain-text. This can be very useful if it's something that would otherwise be hard to layout, e.g. a formula that I would like to send in WhatsApp. Other times, I prefer the text version.

How can I, as a user, choose one clipboard paste method over the other if the target program does support both?

One way I see is directly using snipping tool or pasting the clipboard first into a program like Paint which only knows the image clipboard, then save it as image file and copy that. But I am hoping for a more direct way like a keyboard combination. I would even be okay with third-party solutions, but I'd expect there to be a windows-integrated solution. Googling only leads to questions on how to copy text as an image, which is not my question.

<sub>Specifically I'm using Win10</sub>

Answer (score 0):

> How can I, as a user, choose one clipboard paste method over the other if the target program does support both?

A well written target program will *give you the choice* of what to paste, if it supports more the one format. It is not up to Windows to provide this functionality. A good example is Microsoft Word:

[image: Microsoft Word Paste Special]

If your target program does not give you the choice, then you can look at using a 3rd party clipboard utility (there are many but we cannot recommend anything specific here) and also I would suggest letting the program author know so she can improve it.

Comment: You say there are many 3rd-party utilities, yet I haven't been able to find a useful one yet. What keywords should I google? Or could you maybe name a few?